# Count of Facets in Solr?

Tags: solr, facet

Is there a way to get the count of different facets in solr?

This is an example facet:

- Camera: 20
- Computer: 80
- Monitor: 40
- Laptop: 120
- Tablet: 30

What I need to get here is "5" as in 5 different electronic items. Of course I can count the facet but some of them have many items inside and fetching and counting them really slow it down.

Comment: Have you actually tried faceting? Try creating a sample index with documents  like: `{"id":1,"manf":"Acer","type":"monitor","desc":"19 inch MOnitor"}` . Then do a query for `19 inch monitor` in `desc`. Extra tip: use string fields for faceting.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I'm asking. But it's OK. What Jayendra said is what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply Solr Patch [SOLR-2242](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2242) to get the Facet distinct count.

Answer (score 3):

In SOLR 5.1 will be a "JSON Facet API" with function "unique(state)".
http://yonik.com/solr-facet-functions/

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact answer to this question, but if facet distinct count doesn't work for anyone, you can get that information using `group.ngroups`:

```
group = true
group.field = [field you are faceting on]
group.ngroups = true
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that if you want ungrouped results, you will have to run the query a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the patch is recommended, but the cheesy way to do this for a simple facet, as you have here, is just to use the length of the facet divided by 2. For example, since you are faceting on `type`:

`facetCount = facet_counts.facet_fields.type.length/2`

Comment: assuming a JSON response

Answer (score 0):

Use this GET request:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name/select?json.facet={x:"unique(electronic_items)"}&q=*:*&rows=0
```